# field restriction using

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my grails application:a domain class has 5 fields.I want the third field should be filled only by admin how to accomplish it please help me

example:

```
class abc {
    String f1
    String f2
    string f3
    string f4
    string f5 
    string constraints
}
```

now i want only the admin to access the string f3.to the remaining users it   be disabled
         please help me out......

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about what you have tried and were you are stuck. How are you creating / filling the domain objects? Without specific information I can only point you roughly into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bindData](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) to limit which fields of a domain are being changed when you pass params to it. You could change the list of editable fields depending on whether a user or an admin is editing it.